# image mode - copy buffer-visiting image to clipboard

Tags: images

so I can open a .png file in emacs, copy the content to clipboard so I can paste it to browser for example.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a buffer visiting an image file, you can mark the whole buffer (`M-x mark-whole-buffer`), copy it to the clipboard (`M-x clipboard-kill-ring-save`) and then you can do whatever you want with the contents of that clipboard.

E.g. you can create a new buffer, paste the contents of the clipboard into it (`M-x clipboard-yank`), and save the buffer to a file. You should now have a file identical to the original.

The only problem (which Emacs cannot solve) is what the *other* application will do with the contents of the clipboard. In the example above, the *other* application was Emacs itself and everything worked. But other applications are not always so well-behaved - e.g. you might try `xsel -b -o > foo.jpg` to save the contents of the clipboard to another file. However, `xsel` seems to mangle NUL bytes (presumably, it only handles textual data - and there are probably more problems than just the NUL bytes), so that the resulting file is deemed corrupted by the JPEG libraries. There might be a more intelligent program than `xsel`, but YMMV. However, as mentioned, this is *NOT* an Emacs problem. You have to get the *other* application fixed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the clipboard-* functions, good additions to the normal kill/yank. as you pointed it out, it works inside of emacs, but not with other applications, for example, if I paste to GitHub or here, it is not recognised as image but strong like �PNG IHDxxxxxxx.